# How to get path segments from calling URL including forward slash via RegEx? - ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-web-api-routing

The problem resides in the forward slash. Even if the RegEx matches I won't get the desired result in my controller action. ASP.NET Core does not map path segments if they contain a forward slash. And I'm looking for a workaround in terms of a middleware, routing options, whatever exists.

I'm looking for a solution to get several path segments from the calling url within my controller action including the forward slash via RegEx constraint.

**Example:**

The user calls: `PUT api/v1/model/elements/elementCollection1/subElement1/subSubElement2/value`

Now everything between `elements/` and `/value` shall be passed to an action parameter called `elementPath` in a function like...

```
[HttpPut("api/v1/model/elements/{elementPath}/value")]
public IActionResult PutElementValue(string elementPath, [FromBody] Value value)
{
    //Here is code
}
```

Do you have an idea how to RegEx and map tge match to the elementPath parameter including forward slash? Something like:

`[HttpPut("api/v1/model/elements/{elementPath:regex(<Here shall be the right RegEx>)}/value")]`

It's worth notice that I tried also with * catch-all parameters and it was kind of a hack but it worked for a moment. The problem is that I have another Put-Operation on api/v1/model/elements/{elementPath} without the "/value" appendix. Hence I'm forced to get the elementPath the right way. Plus I want to auto-generate a Swagger Doc from the Controller and everything inside and hacks are not parsed.

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1#route-template-reference):

> You can use an asterisk (*) or double asterisk (**) as a prefix to a route parameter to bind to the rest of the URI. These are called a catch-all parameters. For example, blog/{**slug} matches any URI that starts with /blog and has any value following it, which is assigned to the slug route value. Catch-all parameters can also match the empty string.
>
> The catch-all parameter escapes the appropriate characters when the
> route is used to generate a URL, including path separator (/)
> characters. For example, the route foo/{*path} with route values {
> path = "my/path" } generates foo/my%2Fpath. Note the escaped forward
> slash. To round-trip path separator characters, use the ** route
> parameter prefix. The route foo/{**path} with { path = "my/path" }
> generates foo/my/path.

Change your code like below:

```
[HttpPut("api/v1/model/elements/{**value}")]
public void PutElementValue(string value, [FromBody] string data)
{
    value = value.Replace("/value", "");
}
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I've been there but it doesn't meet my requirements entirely. I need to be able to have other postfixes instead of /value, e.g. /invoke. Additionally, I need a PUT (without /value) request to create the element but independent of its value.

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution, i.e. create and register my own middleware with an URL-encoded element path. That overcomes the issue not mapping the forward slash to any route template.

Solution:

```
app.Use((context, next) =>
            {
                string requestPath = context.Request.Path.ToUriComponent();
                
                if (requestPath.Contains("elements/"))
                {
                    Match valueMatch = Regex.Match(requestPath, "(?<=elements/)(.*)(?=/value|/invoke)");
                    if(valueMatch.Success)
                    {
                        string elementPath = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(valueMatch.Value);
                        requestPath = requestPath.Replace(valueMatch.Value, elementPath);
                        context.Request.Path = new PathString(requestPath);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Match baseMatch = Regex.Match(requestPath, "(?<=elements/)(.*)");
                        if(baseMatch.Success)
                        {
                            string elementPath = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(baseMatch.Value);
                            requestPath = requestPath.Replace(baseMatch.Value, elementPath);
                            context.Request.Path = new PathString(requestPath);
                        }
                    }
                }
                return next();
            });
```

It works but still it feels like a mediocre hack. If you have any idea how to do it in another wa - RegEx in the Action-Route-Template is still favored -  please let me know ;-)